# Is it possible to change %s to variable when importing csv to mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have this code to import my csv to mysql database:

```
import csv
import mysql.connector
import re

change = "hello"  
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='localhost',
                          database='jeremy_db')
file = open('C:\\Users\\trendMICRO\\Desktop\\OJT\\test.csv', 'rb')  
csv_data = csv.reader(file)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor = mydb.cursor()
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table_test(col1,col2,col3,col4)' 'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)',row)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

Can I change the values of %s into my variable `change = "hello"`?

Please help me I'm new to python, I tried every solution but I can't find how to change the values. I tried this `VALUES(hello, %s, %s, %s)',row)` but it doesn't work

Comment: In this particular case, you wouldn't use a variable in the first place, you'd just hardcode the value in the query: `'... VALUES("hello", %s, %s, ...)'`.

Comment: This snippet looks like the right way to use bind variables. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I tried that using hardcode but gives me ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: I don't know what's with the downvote?

Comment: Create variable on outside, like: `var1= "blah blah" ; var2="heyooo"; cursor.execute(var1,var2)`

Comment: Do you understand what `.execute('... %s, %s ...', row)` does exactly?

Comment: yes values per row in csv

Comment: that's why im asking if it is possible to change the whole value and replace it

Comment: So, with `... %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)`, you have 4 placeholders, and `row` must be something with 4 values in it which will get substituted for those placeholders. Now, you want to replace what with what here…?!

Comment: that first %s with variable 'change'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this very particular case, you'd simply hardcode the value in the query:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ... VALUES ("hello", %s, %s, %s)', row)
```

Now you have only three placeholders in your query though, so you need to ensure that `row` is a list with three items. E.g.:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ... VALUES ("hello", %s, %s, %s)', row[1:])
```

If you really wanted to use a variable, you could do something like:

```
row[0] = change
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ... VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
```

Or:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ... VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', [change] + row[1:])
```

Comment: finally! thanks for helping me! row[0] = change is what I think the best